# Reply for C11 French/Steinitz after `5. Nf3 c5`

Tags: analysis, french-defense

When playing C11 French/Steinitz, `6. dxc5 Bxc5` is chosen. Even in [Shredder](http://www.shredderchess.com/online-chess/online-databases/opening-database.html), it's most played in C11 French/Steinitz. What should White best reply after `6. dxc5 Bxc5`??

```
[FEN ""]
1. e4 e6 2. d4 d5 3. Nc3 Nf6 4. e5 Nfd7 5. Nf3 c5 6. dxc5 Bxc5
```

Best Regard, 
Ahmad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plan for white is to **secure the e5 square**. Black's freeing maneuver will be to play f6, and the resulting position will have a backwards pawn on e6. Therefore, white's plan will be to place his bishop on f4 and move his knight to e5, perhaps with support along the e-file from a rook or queen.

A possible variation could continue as follows:

```
rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1

1. e4 e6 2. d4 d5 3. Nc3 Nf6 4. e5 Nfd7 5. Nf3 c5 6. dxc5 Bxc5 7. Bd3 Nc6 8. Bf4 f6 9. exf6 Nxf6 10. O-O O-O 11. Ne5 Bd7 12. Qe2
```

Keep in mind that this isn't the only way of playing the Steinitz. White more commonly plays `5. f4`, bolstering his center pawn on e5 before continuing to develop with Nf3. Also, `6...Nc6` is considered a more accurate move for black, leaving the option of capturing on c5 for a later move and saving a tempo to attack the e5 square.

Comment: thanks for the answer, if the match follows, who would win as seen [advantages good position], because from my game, white going to lose, and if I check your possible variation seem like my game too.. ^^

Comment: In either position it cannot be said who is winning or losing. It's an established variation that has been played in many games. Both sides have their advantages and disadvantages - white occupies the e5 square while black has a central pawn majority. It's up to the player to demonstrate to his or her opponent who has a superior understanding of the position.

Comment: sounds good. ok sir.. ^^.

Answer (score 3):

It may not hit the point of the post, but I would like to show you, how I like to play against e6. I play `Qh5` after `Nfd7`, because it is very aggressive and most of the players don't know how to play against it.

```
[fen ""]
1. e4 e6 2. d4 d5 3. Nc3 Nf6 4. e5 Nfd7 5. Qh5 c5 6. Nf3
```

`cxd4 Nxd4` and now black has to be careful of `Nxe6`

You will play `Be3`, sometimes `Nb5`, often `0-0-0` to protect `d4` with your rock.

You can also try to play `Ng5` with the opportunity to `Qxf7`. After `g6` you play `Qf3`.

**Nxe5 variety**

```
[fen ""]
1. e4 e6 2. d4 d5 3. Nc3 Nf6 4. e5 Nfd7 5. Qh5 c5 6. Nf3 cxd4 7. Nxd4 g6 8. Qg5 Qxg5 9. Bxg5 Nxe5 10. Bf6
```

**Qb6 variety**

```
[fen ""]
1. e4 e6 2. d4 d5 3. Nc3 Nf6 4. e5 Nfd7 5. Qh5 c5 6. Nf3 cxd4 7. Nxd4 Qb6 8. Ndb5 Nc6
```

Comment: I disagree but not downvote. ^^. as I learn, Queen in early in just bad idea, black not to worry if you suggest `5. Qh5 c5 6. nf3 cxd4 7. Nxd4` or `5. Qh5 c5 6. nf3 cxd4 7. Ng5` since black can easily chase the Queen with `7. ... g6 8. ... Nxe5`. as @Andrew Ng says, the plan is to secure the `e5` square because in this case, black will control the center when seize `e5`. If you proposed `Be3` or `Nb5` or `O-O-O` to secure `d4`, it will be useless since black can reply with `Nc6` easily. Believe me, it hard to hold `e5` because White already over aggressive.

Comment: Again `Nc6` you can easily play `Bb5`. `Nxe5` is not really possible, if you play `g6`, I can retort with `Qg5`. `Qxg5` `Bxg5` and you can not play `Nxe5`, because of `Bf6`

Comment: oh my God. sorry for incomplete commenting. If you proposed `5. Qh5 c5 6. nf3 cxd4 7. Nxd4`, it will replied as `7. ... Qb6`, then the possible reply is `8. Nf6` so black can spawn ` 8. ... Nc6`. About `7. ... g6`, I proposed it when face `5. Qh5 c5 6. nf3 cxd4 7. Ng5`. About your `Bf6`, maybe we have different interpretation because in my calculation, Black take `e5` before White bishop came to `f6`. Thanks for appreciation.. ^^

Comment: @AhmadAzwarAnas please see my edited post

Comment: upvote for this time. thanks for the EDIT post, let me followed the `Qb6` variety since the `Nxe5` variety goes wrong for Black (I should take `9. ... a6` at `Nxe5` variety and not take the `e5` pawn too soon. Believe me, you succeeded to drag my Black Queen out. ^^) but I rather choose `8. ... Nc6` than `8. ... a6` in my Black reply at `Qb6` variety. As my view, `Nc6` always good move for Black, maybe you want propose the ninth move so I can analyst it later since `9. Be3` isn't longer proportional..

Comment: I changed the `Qb6` variety (From `a6` to `Nc6`). I think I have many possibilities now. I may need to sacrifice the pawn on `e5` for some initiative.

Comment: yeah, you are right, that was I think.. at last, we'll lost `e5` for some reason. That why as @Andrew Ng said, **secure the e5 square** is most toughest mission for White. And I already liked your `Qb6` variety.